# Is R or Matlab currently faster?

Tags: matlab, performance, r, benchmarking

The most up-to-date performance benchmarks comparison between R and Matlab that I could find are several years out of date: [1](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/dave/rmbenchmark.html) [2](http://www.sciviews.org/benchmark/)

Is anyone aware of a more up-to-date comparison?

Comment: Most of these higher level languages use compiled backends.  In operations as basic as those in your linked benchmarks, the backends likely don't change from one version to the next, so the relative performance doesn't change much.

Comment: I am not sure in which version it first appeared, but matlab currently is able to do parallel computation. I do not know if R or other programs also jqve this feature (and if so how easy it is to implement).

Comment: For one small and specific problem instance check out some timings I did, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134926/benchmarks-of-various-scientific-programming-languages-for-theoretical-modelling, Note that the timings below are also unrealistically in favour of Julia as they don't make use of the strengths of each of the languages tested (e.g. vectorized operations). If you install Microsoft Open R it installs the Intel MKL libs so you have multithreaded fast matrix ops - in my experience if you use that code ported from Matlab to R is usually faster! (often 10x)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The benchmarks on the Julia website [1](http://julialang.org/#High-Performance.JIT.Compiler) [2](http://julialang.org/benchmarks/) include R and Matlab as competitors.

Note that these are benchmarks focusing on testing the pure speed of the language, not the quality of the underlying linear algebra or FFT libraries. The speed for operations that are outsourced to these libraries (such as a large matrix multiplication) can vary a lot depending on the actual libraries used, especially for open source programs: R linked against `libblas` is surely much slower than R linked against `libopenblas` or MKL).

Comment: Great reference, thanks! I'm disappointed to see how badly Matlab does on recursive calls, but maybe not terribly surprised.

Comment: Note that these benchmarks have been critised a lot for not using the strengths of each language, so they would not be an accurate reference in terms of an actual user perspective. See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Python_Meets_Julia_Micro_Performance?lang=en e.g.